# Regular expression with boundary query

Tags: php, regex

I am finding certain words in my data and replacing those keywords with anchor tags.

eg. keyword: disney

data:

```
This is temp data -disney-movie-deaths.html nightmare some more text disney This is some more data.
```

I want to convert this as:

```
This is temp data -disney-movie-deaths.html nightmare some more text <a href="/test.php">disney</a> This is some more
```

I have used regx as: `/\bdisney\b/i`

But problem is that it is converting it as:

```
This is temp data -<a href="/test.php">disney</a>-movie-deaths.html nightmare some more text disney This is some more
```

Can someone face this type of issue?

Comment: You have to phrase your wishes more clearly. When should a substring be replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is sound, but word boundaries are not enough in your case. You see that `\bdisney\b` matches -disney- (*Why shouldn't it?*) For your example I added some spaces behind and after the word you are matching :

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s+(disney)\s+/', '<a href="/test.php">$1</a>', $subject);
```

While this will work for this example it may also not be enough. For example it will not work with `disney.` You can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: With the required whitespace (which are not word characters) at the beginning and ending of the expression, the `\b` assertions are _technically_ redundant but not very hurtful. Removing them would increase efficiency a teeny bit. Two more significant cases to consider are when `disney` is capitalized (i.e. `Disney`) or even used at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use \s instead of \b

```
/\sdisney\s/i
```

\b means word boundary and includes "-" as matching character

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that `disney` is a word by itself. Here's the regex that I used:

```
[\s\.]disney[\s\.$]
```

here's how I tested it:

http://rubular.com/r/YyZMeGITJY

Comment: Whitespace _or a period_ (doesn't need to be escaped in a character class) before the word? Why a period before the word?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
preg_replace("#(?:\s|\A)(disney)(?:\s|\z)#m", "<a>\1</a>", $text);
```